# Batch : list all the subfiles with their absolute path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to generate a classpath automatically with all the `*.jar` files  contained under my `lib` folder.

I can't find a way to list all these files with their absolute path, so that I can build my `classpath` variable.

It seems the `dir` command do not allow to get the absolute path, even when you go recursively with a `/s`.

Basically what I had in mind was something like :

```
set classpath = ./conf
for %%i in (`dir /s /withaboslutepath *.jar`) do set classpath = %classpath%;"%%x"
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: write a program that does this? Your example adds the path for each jar found ..

Comment: Err nope, it did not. At all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created something like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set classpath=./conf
FOR /R . %%x IN (*.jar) do set classpath=!classpath!;"%%~px"
echo !classpath!
endlocal
```

The problem with this solution are the duplicated paths.

Comment: If you have two jar files in the same directory, this directory will be added twice to classpath variable.

Comment: Oh yeah... actually I need to specify the jar files themselves so I replaced your %%~px with only %%x. Thanks a lot !